# Match all commas if there's multiple

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to remove all non-numeric characters from a string. Because people use different thousands separators - and some people thought using commas for this purpose was perfectly fine and not at all easily confused with a decimal point (especially since some countries use commas for decimal points), the regex is shaping up to be annoying.

Here's my current attempt:

```regex
[^\d,.]|[.,](?=.*[.,])|(?<=,.*),
```

1. `[^\d,.]` match all non-numeric characters that aren't commas or dots (because they also use `'` and `’` as separators, not just dots and commas)
2. `[.,](?=.*[.,])` match all commas and dots that are still followed by a dot or comma
3. `(?<=,.*),` match all commas if we've previously seen a comma, already

(I'll probably have to split (2) into two cases, later, but that's not the issue of this question.

The purpose of (3) is that if the string contains multiple commas, we can safely assume that it's used as a thousands separator and not as a decimal point.

I.e.

- `123,456` should be interpreted as `123.456` (and therefore the `,` not match the regex)
- `123,456,789` should be interpreted as `123456789` (and therefore *both* commas match the regex)

Of course `(?<=,.*),` is not valid because look-behinds need be a fixed length and `.*` is not.

**How do I match these pesky commas?**

(The intention is to eventually feed the regex to a Java string replacement method.)

```java
var sanitisedInput = rawInput.replaceAll(<regex>, "")
```

Comment: How do you predict that `123,456` should be treated as `123.456` and not `123456`?

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that all decimal numbers only go to 2 places or less?

Comment: @VighneshRaut I don't. It's an assumption we made and documented. It sounds safer to us given that certain people use the `,` as a decimal point.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, we don't. Afaik, there's a max of 6 decimal places. (And I'll potentially have to adjust the regex afterwards for scientific notation, but one issue at a time.)

Comment: So `123,456.789` and `123.456,789` should become what?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `123,456.789` should become `123456.789` and `123.456,789` should get whoever used that slapped hard, but for our purposes probably should also become `123456.789`

Comment: (since I'm not aware of anybody who puts thousands separators in decimal places)

Answer (score 1):

The below regex pattern might help.

**Pattern:** `(?:(?<=\.)|,)(\d+)(?:(?=\.)|,)`
**Replacement:** `\1`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/KtFX8S/2/

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\.)|,)` - Match either `,` or positive lookbehind of `.`.
- Similarly match pattern at the end
- Use the captured group 1 in the replacement